# Is there a simplest way of choosing starting values in MLE estimation?

Tags: r, math, statistics, mle

I have the following in which I want obtain the MLE estimates and their p-values for the given function and data but I get NA for p-values in the summary. The code is;

```
library(stats4)
library(bbmle)
library(stats)
library(numDeriv)
library('bbmle')
x<- c(0.55, 0.93, 1.25, 1.36, 1.49, 1.52, 1.58, 1.61, 1.64, 1.68, 1.73, 1.81, 2.00, 0.74 ,1.04, 1.27, 1.39, 1.49, 1.53, 1.59, 1.61, 1.66, 1.68, 1.76, 1.82, 2.01,  0.77, 1.11 ,1.28 ,1.42 ,1.50 ,1.54, 1.60, 1.62, 1.66, 1.69, 1.76, 1.84, 2.24, 0.81, 1.13, 1.29, 1.48, 1.50, 1.55 ,1.61, 1.62, 1.66 ,1.70 ,1.77, 1.84, 0.84, 1.24, 1.30 ,1.48, 1.51, 1.55 ,1.61 ,1.63, 1.67, 1.70, 1.78, 1.89
)

hist(x)

########  Expo Half Logi Kuma Weibull

fEHLKUMW<-function(a,b,alpha,vartheta)
  {
-sum(log(2*a*b*alpha*vartheta*(x^(vartheta-1))* exp(-x^vartheta) *((1-exp(-x^vartheta))^(a-1)) * ((1 - (1 -( 1 - exp(-x^vartheta))^a)^b)^(alpha-1)) * (1- (1 - exp(-x^vartheta))^a )^(-b*(alpha+1))
))
}

EHLKUMW.result<-mle2(fEHLKUMW,hessian = NULL,start=list(a=0.8,b=0.9,alpha=0.9,vartheta=0.2),optimizer="nlminb",lower=0)
summary(EHLKUMW.result)
vcov(EHLKUMW.result)
output2<-vcov(EHLKUMW.result)
1.96*sqrt(diag(output2))
solve(output2)
```

*I tried different starting values and datasets but I still get NAs.*

Comment: Do you have a reference for the distribution?

Comment: `  \begin{align*}
\mbox{f}(x;a,b,\alpha,\vartheta) =   2ab\alpha {\vartheta  x^{\vartheta -1}}   e^{-x^{\vartheta}}       \left( 1  -   e^{-x^{\vartheta}} \right ) ^{a-1}   \frac{\left [ 1- {\left[  1- \left(  1  -   e^{-x^{\vartheta}}  \right )^{a}     \right]}^{b} \right ] ^{\alpha - 1}}{{\left[  1- \left(  1  -   e^{-x^{\vartheta}}  \right )^{a} \right]}^{b(\alpha +1)}}
\end{align*} `

Comment: Is there a paper you can reference? Often when a distribution is introduced, the paper includes information that could be helpful for determining MLE.

Comment: Unfortunately its a paper that I am working on. That is why I provided the latex code.

Comment: A much similar paper can be seen here;   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348636418_The_exponentiated_half-logistic_odd_lindley-G_family_of_distributions_with_applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears either the PDF is not formulated correctly or the parameters are not constrained appropriately. The denominator quickly approaches 0 as `vartheta` gets large if `x > 1`:

```
fEHLKUMW(0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 5)
[1] -Inf
```

Comment: The PDF was wrong, Thanks